# Oracle function with table as input parameter

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

How would you create a function in Oracle that has a table as an input parameter and return a string?  Here is my attempt but is returning an error:

```
create or replace type temp_table as object (col_name varchar(100));
/
create or replace type col_table as TABLE of temp_table;
/
create or replace FUNCTION COLUMN_HEADERS
  (col_name in col_table)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
is
  return_string VARCHAR2(4096);
BEGIN
  return_string := '';
  for i in 1 .. col_name.count loop
    return_string := return_string || ' ''' || col_name(i) || ''' as ' || regexp_replace(col_name(i), '[ \+]', '_');
    if i < col_name.count then
      return_string := return_string || ',';
    end if;
  end loop;
  RETURN return_string;
END;
```

I get the following:

```
Error(9,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(9,26): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
```

Which points to this line:

```
return_string := return_string || ' ''' || col_name(i) || ''' as ' || regexp_replace(col_name(i), '[ \+]', '_');
```

My guess is that col_name(i) doesn't return a string but using `VALUE()` or `TO_CHAR()` gives me other errors.  Does anyone know how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference an index in the table using `col_name(i)`, you then also need to reference the object property of that table index as in `col_name(i).col_name`. In your case you used `col_name` both as the object property and as your function argument. For clarity you might change that. This compiled for me:

```
create or replace type temp_table is object (col_name varchar(100));
/
create or replace type col_table is TABLE of temp_table;
/
create or replace FUNCTION COLUMN_HEADERS
  (col_name in col_table)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
is
  return_string varchar2(4096);
BEGIN
  return_string := '';
  for i in 1 .. col_name.count loop
    return_string := return_string || ' ''' || col_name(i).col_name || ''' as ' || regexp_replace(col_name(i).col_name, '[ \+]', '_');
    if i < col_name.count then
      return_string := return_string || ',';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return return_string;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I ended up confusing myself with the nomenclature.